# Ruby on Rails copy S3 file with special characters (%C5) in path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip, special-characters

I have a problem with my attachment system on web page. I store them on amazon S3 using paperclip. I have an option to copy attachment to new file. Everything works fine until there are polish special characters in title, like: ŁĄKA.jpg. Then I get an error:

```
Saving error: Appendix Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError
/Users/michal/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/validations.rb:79:in `raise_record_invalid'
/Users/michal/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
```

My code:

```
instance.appendixes.select {|a| a.temporary? && !a.appendix.exists?}.each do |a|
        a.appendix = S3File.new(a.s3path)
        a.process = false
        a.appendix_url = nil
        puts "CREATING NEW FILE from (temporary?) appendix: #{a.id}, path: #{a.s3path}, is_public: #{a.is_public}, determine_is_public: #{a.determine_is_public}"
        a.is_public = a.determine_is_public
        logger.debug("CREATING NEW FILE from (temporary?) appendix: #{a.id}, path: #{a.s3path}, is_public: #{a.is_public}, determine_is_public: #{a.determine_is_public}")

        a.save! # bo delayed_job
end
```

I'm getting error on a.save! when path is like: `appendixes/appendixes/242/original/%25C5%2581A%25CC%25A8KA.jpg`, but works like charm when it is: `appendixes/appendixes/243/original/laka.jpg` or another file name without polish letters. Anybody had this kind of problem or have suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found what was wrong. I had to replace in a.s3path, the last part with original name (łąka.jpg) and everything works fine. So when I have:
S3File.new(appendixes/appendixes/243/original/łąka.jpg) it works good and finds the correct file on s3 server.